# Auto Fill a Google Doc Template from AppScript including text with hyperlinks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a template made up of placeholders, example {{NAME}} {{SURNMANE}} {{WEBSITE}} where, through AppScript I insert the text. In the case of {{WEBSITE}} I ​​would need to enter the name of the clickable site, therefore with a HYPERLINK inside it.

```
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{NAME}}/g, ""+name);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{SURNAME}}/g,""+surname);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{WEBSITE}}/g,""+website); 
  //"CompanyWebSite" , but I would like to add "hyperlink=www.companywebsite.com/home/..."
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?

Comment: I HAVE THIS GOOGLE DOC TEMPLATE:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdFoQ.png

THIS IS THE RESULT (in red the desired):

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msUNX.png

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that emailBody is a variable that contains HTML.

var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Sorry, i forgot to mention that emailBody is a variable that contains HTML. var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);`, in this case, I think that my answer was not your answer. By this, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I have to study English more.

Comment: ok the solution was trivial, being "emailBody" in HTML I solved it in this way:

emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{WEBSITE}}/g,""+'<a href="'+urlCompany+'"; target="_blank">SITEWEB</a>;');